# Make plots inside the WXMaxima GUI

Tags: gnuplot, maxima

How can I make the plots generated from plotting functions (like plot2d() lie inside the WXMaxima GUI rather than open new Windows? Someone made this in front of me, and I can't find out how he made that.

Thank you.

Comment: Under the menu `Plot -> Plot Format`.

Comment: @Christoph Thanks, but No, that doesn't do it. I think, though, this would've been very obvious, wouldn't it?

Comment: Hmm, right. But it works for me, if I set `Plot -> Plot 2d -> Format` to `inline`. This uses `wxplot2d` instead of `plot2d`. Thought if would be configurable also via `Plot -> Plot Format`.

Comment: @Christoph I can use wxplot2d(), but the option inline isn't there.

Comment: Don't know why this happens, but I maybe you have a problem with your installation (OS? wxMaxima version?), as the `inline` should work.

Comment: @Christoph Ubuntu 12.04, wxmaxima from repos.

Answer (score 7):

Just put a "wx" in front of your plot command: use `wxplot`, `wxdraw`, `wxdraw2d` or similar instead of `plot`, `draw` or `draw2d`.

Comment: As you can see in the comments, this doesn't work for the OP.